# ERROR HRESULT: 0x80073CF3 Deployment package UWP App fails

Tags: deployment, package, uwp

Can anyone help to fix this problem pleas? I can't deploy my universal app.

> Error : Windows cannot install package . because this package depends on another package that could not be found. This package requires minimum version 1.0.23302.0 of framework Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0 published by CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US to install.

[image: ERROR HRESULT: 0x80073CF3 Deployment UWP App]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved these problems by making Win 10 updates and sdk updates from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 5):

you have to deploy the package dependencies first. Usually, Visual Studio creates a "Dependencies" folder containing the required packages
Check out the Device Portal's Apps section.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/deviceportal

Comment: And for UWP there will be different dependencies when you compile for .NET Native. Something nice to keep in mind!

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: @Shimmy link fixed